# BeautifulSoup and remove entire tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm working with BeautifulSoup. I wish that if I see the tag -a href- the entire line is deleted, but, actually, not.

By example, if I have :

```
<a href="/psf-landing/">
This is a test message
</a>
```

Actually, I can have :

```
<a>
This is a test message
</a>
```

So, how can I just get :

```
This is a test message
```

Here is my code :

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(content_driver, "html.parser")
for element in soup(text=lambda text: isinstance(text, Comment)):
    element.extract()
for titles in soup.findAll('a'):
    del titles['href']
tree = soup.prettify()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `.extract()` method. In your case, you're just deleting an attribute

```
for titles in soup.findAll('a'):
    if  titles['href'] is not None:
        titles.extract()
```

Comment: Instead of checking `if  titles['href'] is not None`, you can use `find_all('a', href=True)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here,you can see the detailed examples [Dzone NLP examples](https://dzone.com/articles/nlp-tutorial-using-python-nltk-simple-examples)

what you need is :

```
text = soup.get_text(strip=True)
```

This is the sample example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request 
response = urllib.request.urlopen('http://php.net/') 
html = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"html5lib")
text = soup.get_text(strip=True)
print (text)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the [**`unwrap()`**](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#unwrap) method. Have a look at the following snippet:

```
html = '''
<a href="/psf-landing/">
This is a test message
</a>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
for el in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    el.unwrap()

print(soup)
# This is a test message
```

Using `href=True` will match only the tags that have `href` as an attribute.